# nested ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

repeat inside ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in OauthSwaggerData.paths " > 
    <div class="col col-100">{{key}}</div>   
    <div ng-repeat="APIDetails in OauthSwaggerData.paths['/key']">
        <div class="col col-100"><h4>Summary</h4> </div>
        <div class="col col-100">{{APIDetails.summary}}</div>
        <div class="col col-100"><h4>Description</h4> </div>
        <div class="col col-100">{{APIDetails.description}}</div>
        <div class="col col-100"><h4>Parameters</h4> </div> 
    </div>
</li>
```

In the first line i want to display the keys which are available , which is working fine. In the second ng-repeat I want to pass the name of the key which i have selected. 
e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="APIDetails in OauthSwaggerData.paths['/token']"> .
```

When i hardcode this value i am getting the desired output. But i want to pass the "key " from the first loop in this second loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="APIDetails in OauthSwaggerData.paths['/key']">
```

which i not working fine.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried 
<div ng-repeat="APIDetails in OauthSwaggerData.paths['/{{key}}']">  this also.

Comment: You want to do this: `ng-repeat="APIDetails in value"` ?

Comment: @BobSponge You saved my day dear. Thank you very much . I am so happy :)

Answer (score 2):

In your third line try:

```
<div ng-repeat="APIDetails in OauthSwaggerData.paths['/' + key]">
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in OauthSwaggerData.paths " > 
<div class="col col-100">{{key}}</div>   
<div ng-repeat="APIDetails in value">
    <div class="col col-100"><h4>Summary</h4> </div>
    <div class="col col-100">{{APIDetails.summary}}</div>
    <div class="col col-100"><h4>Description</h4> </div>
    <div class="col col-100">{{APIDetails.description}}</div>
    <div class="col col-100"><h4>Parameters</h4> </div> 
</div>
```